# Find the area bounded by the curves $y=1-\cos(2x)$, $y = 0$, for $0\leq x \leq 2 \pi$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the area bounded by the curve $y=1-\cos(2x)$, the $x$ axis, and the lines $x=0$ and $x=2\pi$

Can someone please show me how this question is completed. This is causing much confusion.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to start it off.

Comment: For starters, draw a graph of the function over that interval.

Comment: already done that

Comment: OK then, tell us what you have done so far.

Comment: I've only drawn that diagram.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, we plot the graph, and look at the region to be integrated. Below, compliments of Wolfram Alpha, we have the graph of $\color{blue}{y = 1 - \cos 2\pi}$, above the line $\color{purple}{y = 0}$, from $x = 0$ to $x = 2\pi$:

[image]

From here, it's relatively straight forward: our bounds of integration are from $x = 0$ to $x = 2\pi$, and the integrand = $(\underbrace{1 - \cos 2x}_{\text{upper curve}}\quad - \underbrace{0}_{\text{lower curve}}) \,dx = (1 - \cos 2x)\,dx$

Putting this together gives us $$\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi} (1 - \cos 2x)\,dx \quad & = \quad \int_0^{2\pi} \,dx \quad - \quad \int_0^{2\pi} \cos 2x\, dx\\ \\
& = x\Big\vert_0^{2\pi} \quad -\quad \dfrac 12 \sin 2x\Big\vert_0^{2\pi}\\ \\
& = (2\pi - 0) - \frac 12 (\sin(4\pi) - \sin(0))\\ \\ 
& = (2\pi - 0) - \frac 12(0 - 0) \\ \\
& = 2\pi\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you please show me the next step, sort of stuck..

Comment: Recall, for $\int 1 \,dx = \int dx = x $, and for $\int \cos 2x\,dx$, we can put $u = 2x$, $\;du = 2\,dx \implies dx = \frac 12 du$. Then we have $$\int \cos 2x \,dx = \int \frac 12 \cos u \,du = \frac 12 \sin u = \frac 12 \sin 2x$$

Comment: @amWhy: Nice, with pictures and all. +1

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the integration $$\displaystyle\int^{2\pi}_01-\cos(2x)dx=x+\sin(2x)|_0^{2\pi}=2\pi+\sin4\pi\,-0-\sin0=2\pi.$$ If you are not sure what is happening, please google search "geometrical meaning of definite integral".